# Where should I place test data files created during unit test?

Tags: java, maven

As a part of unit test, in my maven java project, I have to create some files.
Although I clean up after every test but still to be at safer side, I want to place them in folder which should be in my project. Can you suggest me if 'target' folder is the right choice?

I can place them outside in a project but then to make it easily executable in all machines this will be tedious. Also, I might file or directory permissions issue in machines not directly controlled by my team.

Comment: The target `folder` is the only choice...than you can remove all via defaults which means simply via `mvn clean` no extra configuration needed etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could choose the `target` folder, because the [maven clean plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html) will delete it by default (at least when you didn't change the configuration) when `mvn clean` is invoked. You also should be able to write to the `target` directory, so this should work fine.

Nonetheless, in case you use JUnit for your project, I would suggest to use the built-in feature of `TemporaryFolder` class.
This will create a folder in a temporary directory and delete it after every testcase. See usage example below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;

public class TempFolderTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        File file = tempFolder.newFile();
    }

}
```

When you actually want to use `target` directory, you can even give this as an argument to the constructor. But in general I see no need to specify the location of the test files yourself.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder(new File("target"));
```

Comment: Thanks @SilverNak, I didn't know about TemporaryFolder. I have not used it so dar but I will try to use it in my coming developments.