# Files to test in JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, junit

I'm currently writing tests to a class. And this class takes in two files in its constructor. So I need to create two files to initialize an object of that class.
So what's the best way to do that? Simply create a .txt in the project directory or what?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a test resources folder (which is the standard approach in maven), then pass files from that test resources folder to your class.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45084159/7677308)

Answer (score 1):

I advise to use Maven Project.
There would be a good point to do that - `src/test/resources`

UPD: gradle has similar directory structure:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout

Comment: forgot to mention that the project is an assignment and it's a gradle project

Comment: Whichever is your favourite build tool (Maven, Gradle, Ant...) but try not to couple your project to an IDE as collaboration might be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html)rule, and create files in there.

This will ensure that they are cleaned up after the test has been run, you don't get interference between tests etc.